# Flutter installation Error in updating SDK Manager in MAC Catalina

Tags: android, macos, shell, flutter, dependencies

I am trying to install Flutter dependencies in **MAC Catalina**.

After running following command in **ZSHELL**

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Got error as

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
/Users/hari/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

So by running the above command, I am getting the error shown

```
hari@Apples-MBP ~ % /Users/hari/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
hari@Apples-MBP ~ %
```

Below is the screen shot for the same.

[image]

> I am having Android Studio 4.0 Preview installed . Android 10.0(Q) and
>   Android 9.0(Pie) is already present.

**Anybody got similar issues in MAC Catalina?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reverting back Java version to `1.8`.

Modified `JAVA_HOME` to corresponding path version.

Without any more complication, issues were resolved!